The POST hidden link based on Country
Dears,
I try to scrap the price from this page
https://www.perthmint.com/shop/bullion/minted-bars/kangaroo-5g-minted-gold-bar/
in the Google spreadsheet using this code
=IMPORTXML("https://www.perthmint.com/shop/bullion/minted-bars/kangaroo-5g-minted-gold-bar/","//*[@id='mainContent']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/h1")
but nothing was ingested.
my investigation goes to:
I am from a country that not be able to ship the products to, therefore we have to send a link that shows the Australian country shipping place
thanks
